# python 3 - math.sqrt - a float is required

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use a square root as the count for a counted loop, but I keep getting the error "a float is required." I have tried every way that I can think of to convert the value provided by math.sqrt to a float, but I am still getting the message.

Code:

```
from random import randrange
import math


def getInfo():

    tilesNum = float(input("Please enter number of tiles now: "))



def procedure(tilesNum):

    countX = 0

    SqRoot = float(math.sqrt(tilesNum))

    print(SqRoot)

    for i in range(float(SqRoot)):

        countX = countX + 1
        countY = 0


        for i in range(float(SqRoot)):
            countY = countY + 1
            terrain = randrange(1, 5)

            if terrain == 1:
                print("terrain on tile", countX, countY, "is frozen")

            elif terrain == 2:
                print("terrain on tile", countX, countY, "is flooded")

            elif terrain == 3:
                print("terrain on tile", countX, countY, "is impeded by   rocks")

            else:
                print("terrain on tile", countX, countY, "is overgrown")




def main():

    tilesNum = getInfo()

    procedure(tilesNum)

main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rainy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\PBA prototype (problem).py", line 50, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Rainy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\PBA prototype (problem).py", line 48, in main
    procedure(tilesNum)
  File "C:\Users\Rainy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\PBA prototype (problem).py", line 15, in procedure
    SqRoot = float(math.sqrt(tilesNum))
TypeError: a float is required
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

- Rainy

Comment: You got the correct answer from @Robᵩ. Next time you get a message like that, you should check what tilesNum is - place a breakpoint on the line and check. Or add a print statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `return` statement. Try this:

```
def getInfo():
    tilesNum = float(input("Please enter number of tiles now: "))
    return tilesNum
```

Since your `getInfo()` has no explicit return statement, it returns `None` implicitly. Your `main()` then passes `None` into `procedure()`. Inside `procedure()`, you pass `None` into `math.sqrt()`. `math.sqrt()` complains with a `TypeError`.

Comment: Good answer. I think it can be further improved by explaining how the three `tilesNum`s are three different variables. I suspect this is where some of the confusion is coming from.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the answer. It worked perfectly. Please pardon my green-ness. It's great though to have experienced programmers to help out newbs/noobs like me haha.

Thanks to you too, NPE, for your addition to Rob's answer.